# NullPointerException from `getWritableDatabase` in a fragment

Tags: android, sqlite

My problem here is whenever the onCreateView() is executed, the line `db = dh.getWritableDatabase();` gives me a NullPointerException, I also looked at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449384/getwritabledatabase-throwing-null-pointer-exception-in-my-apps) question but we have a different situation though. Does my code lack something? Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FavMed extends Fragment {

    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(this.getContext());

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav_med, container, false);

        try{
            db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("log1",e.toString());
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

---

Here's the log

[image]

Comment: Can you post the logs.

Comment: Try to intalize databasehelper `constructor`  in `onAttach()` and pass activity context from `onAttach()` method.

Comment: @Madonah Syombua i updated my question with the log in it

Comment: I see have you tried the given solution. 

Comment: Yes.. @NiVeR just saved my life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify the code like this:

```
public SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHelper dh = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav_med, container, false);

    try{
        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this.getContext());
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("log1",e.toString());
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

The problem is that when the Fragment is created, the activity may be not ready yet, so the context is null because refers to the activity where the fragment is located. Is a matter of timing. That's why the creation of the helper should be delayed to a later stage where the context will be present.

Comment: Can you please tell me why the instantiation of DatabaseHelper outside the onCreateView() gives me the exception earlier?

Comment: Updated the answer with some details.

Answer (score 0):

Context is not available when you instantiate the fragment. Another possible solution compared to the one from @NiVeR would be the following:

```
public class FavMed extends Fragment {

public SQLiteDatabase db;
DatabaseHelper dh = null;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    dh = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fav_med, container, false);

    try{
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("log1",e.toString());
    }

    return rootView;
}
```